# Documentation for QBO Account model missing documentation for Type attribute

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

The account attribute SubType has to match an enumeration from QboAccountDetailTypeEnum for the online version. Specifying "Asset" as the sub_type raises the following exception:

"IntuitRequestException: The account type isn't valid."

Enumeration docs: http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0400_QuickBooks_Online/0400Enumerations_and_Codes

Online Account model docs: http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0400_QuickBooks_Online/Account

Desktop Account model docs:
http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Account

It looks as though QBD has a "Type" attribute and the online version just has "SubType".

QBO:
SubType(QboAccountDetailTypeEnum)

QBD:
SubType(AccountSubtypeEnum)
Type(AccountTypeEnum)

AccountTypeEnum has "Assets" and your basic bucket account types: Asset, Equity, Expense, Liability, Revenue. In the API explorer it outputs a  and .

QB doesn't document the "Type" attribute on QBO but you can set it and it'll accept it and store it. It's not in the API explorer or the API docs on QBO, it's on QBD though. I have to assume that it's an attribute that'll continue to be there going forward especially since it's on QBD which is the older technology.

Can someone from Intuit clarify the behavior for this or if this is a known issue/discrepancy?

Comment: Can you post your request/response XML?  'Asset' is not a valid value for SubType.  It must be one of the values listed under the QboAccountDetailTypeEnum, such as AccountsPayable, AccountsReceivable, AccumulatedAdjustment, AccumulatedAmortization, AccumulatedAmortizationOfOtherAssets,etc.

Comment: I got that part of it now, I guess my issue now sits with why "Type" isn't supported with QBO. I thought it was storing it but this latest test didn't persist the "Type" attribute. Is it just assumed that because of the selected "SubType" it'll go ahead and pick the appropriate primary "Type"?

Comment: Correct. The account type (Asset, Equity, etc.) is set based on the subtype that you pass in the Create request.  You cannot explicitly set the account type in QBO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per Peter,
'Asset' is not a valid value for SubType. It must be one of the values listed under the QboAccountDetailTypeEnum, such as AccountsPayable, AccountsReceivable, AccumulatedAdjustment, AccumulatedAmortization, AccumulatedAmortizationOfOtherAssets,etc.

thanks
Jarred